# ajax, long polling and managing two minute retries

Tags: ajax, jquery, node.js, long-polling

One of the AJAX requests to my node.js server can occasionally take more than two minutes. I've discovered that when the server takes longer than two minutes, the client resends the AJAX request. This caused the server to get even more bogged down since it started a second expensive process.

To get around that, I implemented a long-polling solution on the server. The client makes an ajax call to a check function on the server that just checks if the process is completed and rechecks every five seconds and gets back to the client when it is done.

However, I still have a variation of the two-minute problem. A second check AJAX still call comes in after two minutes. Then both checks are running and it seems that only the new one will communicate back to the client.

What is the best way to address this?

- Is there a way to configure or disable the two-minute ajax resend?
- Is there a better way to manage subsequent duplicate requests to the server?
- Do I need to implement a timeout on the client instead of the server?

I'm using jQuery AJAX calls, a node.js server on the Chrome browser

UPDATE: From the [node.js docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/all.html), "all incoming connections have a default timeout of 2 minutes". I'm still interested in suggestions about best practice for coding long running server requests where the client doesn't need to know anything until the server finishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be clear about what is happening:

1. Client sends request "do this thing for me ..."
2. Node code starts an asynchronous operation (or several chained together)
3. Two minutes pass
4. HTTP request times out
5. Client re-sends request
6. Now there are two requests running
7. And so on until there are a ton of requests running

I think I've heard this called "the dogpile effect".  I don't know of any standard libraries in node.js or jQuery to help you although someone had started work on a caching proxy to help with this in the case where the response would be "cacheable":

https://github.com/simonw/dogproxy

So, you'd have to design your own system to get around this.

There are different ways to handle batch jobs and often it depends on the nature of the job.

What I've seen most commonly for tasks that take a long time is the API returns an ID for the job right away and then then client uses polling (or long polling) to wait for the job to complete.  You'll need some kind of database to store the state (% complete) and result of the job and allows the client to wait for that status to change.  This can also allow you to "cancel" a job, although in that case the server-side code has to check periodically to see if it has been cancelled.

Just be aware that wherever you store the job status has to be shared by all nodes in a cluster if the application is or will be scaled up later.  You might use some kind of high speed lightweight storage system like memcached or redis for this.

Comment: Thanks for clearly explaining what I've been stumbling towards. It seems like an inconsistency in the asynchronous philosophy of node to have to do polling.

Comment: Would you expect to see the second request (the retry) in the Chrome Inspector?  I'm having the same behavior described above of retry-after-2-minutes but no indication if it's the client retrying or the server doing it.

Comment: Emile, I don't think the server is generally capable of triggering a retry on the client - once the connection is dumped, the client has to reconnect itself.  Thus, it SHOULD show up in the Chrome Inspector if you are recording network events.  However, if the retry was being performed by some intermediate proxy then you wouldn't see it on the client and you would have no control over it.   It generally doesn't work out well to make the client wait more than a couple seconds for a server operation to finish because of the stateless unreliable mdeium of HTTP and the Internet in general.

Comment: Paul: It is an inconsistency with the asynchronous philosophy.  In an ideal asynchronous world you'd give the server an URL to send the reply to instead of waiting for or polling for a response.  Unfortunately there's a major assymetry between clients and servers on the internet when it comes to "reachability", so it's very hard for the server to call back to a client (assuming javascript even provided a mechanism for doing that).  Long polling works alright and doesn't incur THAT much extra overhead.  These long running operations should be fairly rare for most applications.